# Authenticity Tokens in Clojure to combat CSRF?

Tags: clojure, csrf

What Clojure library (or libraries) exist to fight [cross-site request forgeries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [Ring](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring), check out [ring-anti-forgery](https://github.com/weavejester/ring-anti-forgery): Ring middleware that  "prevents CSRF attacks by providing a randomly-generated anti-forgery token."